# Zip file created in servlet, but filename is only correct sometimes

Tags: java, servlets, zip, filenames

I am generating pdf's based on a user's choice and zipping them together in a servlet.  I give the zip folder a file name, but when I use the web app to download the zip folder, the zip folder's file name is not always the file name that I gave to it.  When I download the folder, it either (1) has the correct name (happens most of the time) or (2) it has the name of the servlet without the .zip suffix.  In either case, the contents of the folder are correct.  Scenario (2) is only happening in two particular cases. (i.e., when trying to bundle specific pdfs together.)

During the debugging process, I checked to make sure that the file name is indeed correct.  Also, no exceptions are being thrown, so I cannot even begin to understand what is wrong.

Code

```
    java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream myZOS = new java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

    java.util.List<String> cIDs = Arrays.asList(request.getParameterValues("cID"));
    String rID = request.getParameter("rID");
    String rName = "";
    String cNames = "";

    for(Integer i = 0; i < cIDs.size(); i++)
    {
        if(!cNames.equals(""))     //separate names with _
            cNames += "_";

        Foo myFoo = new Foo(Integer.valueOf(rID),Integer.valueOf(cIDs.get(i)));
        rName = myFoo.getName();
        cNames += myFoo.getCID();
        PDFDoc myPDFDoc = new PDFDoc(myFoo, request.getServerName());
        java.util.zip.ZipEntry myZE = new java.util.zip.ZipEntry(myPDFDoc.getFilename());
        myZOS.putNextEntry(myZE);
        myZOS.write(myPDFDoc.getPDF());
    }

    logger.log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, "rName: ".concat(rName).concat("; cNames: ").concat(cNames));  //correct name

    response.setContentType("application/zip");

    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + rName + "_" + cNames + ".zip\"");
    response.getOutputStream().flush();
    myZOS.close();
```

Comment: I bet the problem is not in this part of the code. Would you mind posting the servlet and PDFDoc?

Comment: The code that I posted was the servlet's `doGet` method.  (Sorry for not mentioning it.)  I have tested the `PDFDoc` code and it works without exception.  (All it does is use fop to convert an xml to a pdf.)  Even in the case where the zip folder's file name is wrong, the PDF's inside have correct content and filenames.

Comment: could you provide us an example of some input data that generates the wrong names?

Comment: Well, the inputs of interest are byte arrays containing the desired PDF's. (So, I don't think human inspection of those would be practical.)  Since fop is handling the conversion of the xml files, all I can say for certain is that the PDF's are created correctly and that there are no issues with the xml's that the PDF's were created from.  If the PDF's were created incorrectly by fop, the documents would be inaccurate; if it were a problem with the xml, fop would have thrown an exception.  I have also checked the xml files manually, and they are formatted correctly.

Comment: so, let's recap. You have an error that sometimes happens sometimes not, no exception thrown, no other code can be shown, no example of wrong names can be provided and the only snippet of code we have seems not to be the source of the problem. You have the code, the environment and the bug. I don't. :-) tell me how can we help you find your bug :-)

Comment: Figured it out.  You have to do `response.setContentType("application/zip")` before opening the outputstream.  Otherwise the servlet doesn't know what kind of content it is and will just return the servlet's name as the file name. 

Why it only mattered for a few of them remains a mystery.

Comment: Glad to hear that :-) provide your own answer and accept it so you can help someone else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do `response.setContentType("application/zip")` before opening the outputstream.  Otherwise the servlet doesn't know what kind of content it is and will just return the servlet's name as the file name.